# Creating Filter Co-Efficient Types for a biquad?

Tags: filter

i have a biquad filter which i want to use with different filter types.

to calculate the biquad coefficients for a onepole lowpass *with butterworth topology* i am using the following:

```
**A0** = (1.0/(1.0 + sqrt(2.)*(1.0/tanh(pi*(F/SR))) + (1.0/tanh(pi*(F/SR))) * (1.0/tanh(pi*(F/SR)))))

**A1** = (1.0/(1.0 + sqrt(2.)*(1.0/tanh(pi*(F/SR))) + (1.0/tanh(pi*(F/SR))) * (1.0/tanh(pi*(F/SR))))) * 2.

**A2** = (1.0/(1.0 + sqrt(2.)*(1.0/tanh(pi*(F/SR))) + (1.0/tanh(pi*(F/SR))) * (1.0/tanh(pi*(F/SR)))))

**B1** = 2.0*(1.0/(1.0 + sqrt(2.)*(1.0/tanh(pi*(F/SR))) + (1.0/tanh(pi*(F/SR))) * (1.0/tanh(pi*(F/SR))))) * (1.0 - (1.0/tanh(pi*(F/SR)))*(1.0/tanh(pi*(F/SR))))

**B2** = (1.0/(1.0 + sqrt(2.)*(1.0/tanh(pi*(F/SR))) + (1.0/tanh(pi*(F/SR))) * (1.0/tanh(pi*(F/SR))))) * (1.0 - sqrt(2.0) * (1.0/tanh(pi*(F/SR))) + (1.0/tanh(pi*(F/SR)))*(1.0/tanh(pi*(F/SR))))
```

i also have butterworth highpass, bandpass, and bandreject working. (and of course, "classic" biquad coeffs)

in order to do the same for other filter types such as elliptic, chebychev, or whatever might exist i tried to derive code in the form i need from comparing existing code, e.g. from matlab - but i dont get it to work at all.

Would somebody be able to provide me the correct math for whatever other filter types in a similar manner than above?

(F = Frequency in Hertz, which is the only variable/input to this expression)